# Android video streaming Socket MediaRecorder (Broadcasting)

Tags: android

I'm beginner work with android. But I very need your help.
I have a project with streaming video Broadcasting video. I can not find good sample, where will be realized recording Video from Camera, sending (uploading) stream to server and downloading (getting streaM) from server to Player.
Please help me with this questions
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sipdroid open source project

https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout